# SQL, how to use count the number of unit in same table structure but different id

Tags: sql

`unit_table`
**Unit_id       Status_id

1                 1

2                 2

3                 2

4                 3

5                 3**

Above show a sample table with 2 different table structures which is unit_id and status_id, now i want to write a query to find out there is how many unit which status_id is 1,2 or 3. I have write a SQL as shown below : -

```
select count(unit_id) 
where status_id =1 ..
```

However i am stucked at here..because i do not know how to use where clause to count the unit with different status id.

Anyone has any idea to do this ?

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`!

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE status_id IN (1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: @jarlh thansk for your hint bro !!

Comment: @GordonLinoff thx gor your hint bro! i will try it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT status_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE status_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY status_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion bro !! i will try it !!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Status_id FROM unit_table GROUP BY Status_id
```

If you want to count how many distinct Unit_id you have per Status_id then:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Unit_id), Status_id FROM unit_table GROUP BY Status_id
```

Hope it helps